# bindings defined in file ibm-web-bnd.xml are not processed

Tags: java, web-applications, binding, websphere

I'm trying to deploy a web application on websphere 8.5.5. I have defined the application bindings in the WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml file, but when i install the application in websphere, the bindings file is not processed and I need to specify the bindings manually, from the administration console.

If I use the same file in another web application, everything is ok and the bindings are correctly processed.

Can anyone help me find the reason why the two applications are behaving differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.**xml** file is only processed when you have a web.xml defined using a version greater than 2.4. If you have a web.xml with a version equal or prior to 2.4 you have to use a ibm-web-bnd.**xmi** bindings file.

In my case the two web applications are using different web.xml versions, 2.4 and 2.5, and thus the different behaviour